# html.TextArea() value after PostBack

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I'm new to MVC and I'm using Razor.  I have a form where the user can edit text fields then click save.  Here's my form

```
@using (Html.BeginForm(null, null, FormMethod.Post, new { id = "form" }))
{
    ...
    @Html.TextArea("Description", Model.Description, 5, 50, null)
    ...
}
```

After I tested this and verified it was working, I added some server side checking.  For the description field, I checked that it wasn't blank.  If it wasn't then display an error message.  Here's my code for this

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult EditContract(Contract contract)
{
    if (contract.Description == null)
    {
        contract.Description = string.Empty;
    }
    contract.Description = contract.Description.Trim();

    if (contract.Description == string.Empty)
    {
        ViewBag.Message = "Description can't be blank";

        contract.LoadContract(contract.ContractId);

        return View(contract);
    }
    ...
}
```

This actually all worked as I wanted.  However, I was surprised that it did.  My code loaded the record from the database and passed it to the view as the model.  How did the view know not to set the value of the textbox to the value from the model and leave it as what the user last entered?

**EDIT**

I created a simple project to test this out thinking something in my project could be effecting how this is working.  This simple project is an empty MVC 4 project using razor.  I then added the following code.

MyModel.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace MvcApplication6.Models
{
    public class MyModel
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
}
```

HomeController.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using MvcApplication6.Models;

namespace MvcApplication6.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            var myModel = new MyModel();
            return View(myModel);
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Index(MyModel model)
        {
            model.Name = "something";
            return View(model);
        }
    }
}
```

Index.cshtml

```
@model MvcApplication6.Models.MyModel

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Name)
    <br />
    <input type="submit" value="submit" />
}
```

I would like it to show 'something' in the textbox after the user clicks submit but it doesn't.  It has whatever the user has previously entered.  What do I need to do to get it to show 'something'?

Thanks,

Comment: As an aside, look at String.IsNullOrWhitespace() and save yourself some key strokes.

Comment: Thanks.  That snippet would be shorter if I had used IsNullOfWhitespace().  Howevever, I would still need to have an if/else later to check for null or this line 'command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Description", contract.Description));' would throw an exception is description was null.  The way I have it would be 1 line shorter.  Also, this a pattern I used in regular ASP.NET to pass 'cleaned up' values back to the user if validation fails.  However, since MVC seems to want to use what the user last entered instead of what's in the model I'm not sure how I'll get that to work.

Comment: Can you set a breakpoint on your return line and check to see the value of `contract.Description` at that point?

Comment: Yes, that's one of the first things I did.  contract.Description contains the original value from the database.  Yet the rendered page has the value the user entered.

Answer (score 0):

Usually if I want a field passed back to the controller I will use the for helper

```
@Html.TextAreaFor(x => x.Description, ...)
```

This will populate the field with the data from the model and if the field is changed, the changed value is what is sent back to the controller.  I found with the non "for" helpers if I named the field the same as my model name (as you did) it will still pass the changed value back to the controller.  MVC binds the value to the field on load but what is sent back to the controller is just the changed values.  Hopefully this helps :)

Comment: Hmm, TextArea and TextAreaFor seem to do the same thing.  However, I like the TextAreaFor better since it's strongly type.  I think that's the purpose of the *For functions.  I think I'll use them more from now on.  Although this doesn't really answer my question.  I'm guessing the reason my example above works as it does is the TextBox functions do different things based on if the current http method is HttpPost or HttpGet.  If it's HttpGet it uses the value from my model and if HttpPost it uses what the user last entered.  I guess I was looking for confirmation of this.

Comment: My understanding is get and post send the same data,  the difference is in how the data is sent.  I have never seen a difference in data sent between the 2 different methods.